# Problem with execution of a self-built ghostscript binary on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat, ghostscript

I've been trying, for a few days now, to run GhostScript on a Red Hat 7.3.1 Server, without success. I tried running the binary provided by Ghostscript, but got a "bad ELF interpreter" error, and can't build from source code on this server, due to not being able to use gcc (I'm very limited to what I can do, the server being hosted by another company.

So I had the idea to build from source code on an ubuntu virtual machine by using ./configure and make, and transfer the binary to the server. But at execution of the binary on the server, I get a "Permission denied" error. I dont know much about the make command or, for that matter, about linux. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is my idea bad from the start ?

Comment: The pre-built Linux binary is of limited use: it's built on an old "lowest (hopefully) common denominator" Linux VM - it doesn't surprise me that it doesn't always work. It is, at best, only meant for testing. As to your "Permission denied" error, transferring the binary file from the VM to the server may have lost the executable permission flag. Maybe try (in a terminal on the server) "chmod a+x <path to>/gs". And trying running it again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Running chmod did it, but now I'm running on a "Segmentation fault" error.

Comment: I would *guess* that's a difference between dependency versions between the VM where the exe was built, and the server on which it is running. But it's pretty hard to really know.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to look into all that

Comment: Thinking about it, the "bad ELF interpreter" may be down to a 32bit vs 64 bit mismatch. On the server command line, do "uname -a" it will show either "x86_64" or (maybe) "i686" somewhere in the output. If the former, you'll want the "ghostscript-9.50-linux-x86_64.tgz" binary download, if the latter the "ghostscript-9.50-linux-x86.tgz". Worth checking, I think.

Comment: FWIW, when building the binary for download, I use the following configure options: "--disable-contrib --disable-threading --disable-fontconfig --disable-cups --disable-gtk --with-libiconv=no --without-libidn --without-libpaper --without-x" to minimise reliance on other libraries. The downside of that is you'll lose certain features, but it may be worth experimenting with combinations of the above options list.

Comment: The server is x86_64, but showed the bad ELF interpreter error on both the 32 and 64 bits versions of the software. I tried the building options you suggested, but it didn't work unfortunately. But I'll keep looking in that direction. Thank you very much for your help !